# Full page jscrollpane keyboard arrow keys focus

Tags: keyboard, focus, jscrollpane

I have two problems which are demonstrated in the [jscrollpane website](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html). My first problem is that in order to focus this page you need to click on the actual page before you can use the keyboard arrow keys to scroll. My second problem, which is my main problem, is that if you adjust the page size so that the width scroll bar appears on the page, you need to click the mouse on the bottom right scroll bar square before you can use the keyboard arrow keys to scroll through the page. For example just clicking on the page itself will not focus the scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$("#container_element").hover(function () {
    $("#scrollable_element").focus(); //makes it gain focus
});
```

to make your element cain focus when you hover over it (no need for clicking).

and in case you want it to lose focus when you stop hovering, use this:

```
$("#container_element").mouseleave(function () {
 $("#scrollable_element").blur(); //makes it lose focus
});
```